# How to change one byte int to two bytes in Python?

Tags: python, network-programming

I am making a basic server/client program, and I am making the client in Python. I have to format the message before I send it. The first field is for message length. I can compute the message length, but I need to store the value in the first two bytes of my bytearray. If the message length is less than 256, it should be only one byte. How can I force the number to be 2 bytes without just tacking a 0x00 onto the front?

Comment: The `struct` module may be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`struct` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).  For example, to pack an integer into an unsigned two-byte value in network order (big-endian), you would do this:

```
> my_value = 1234
> packed_bytes = struct.pack('>H', my_value)
> print packed_bytes
'\x04\xd2'
```

Comment: If my_value was equal to a one byte value like 150, how could I force that into the first two bytes of packed_bytes even though it would technically occupy only 1 byte? I just need to be able to handle 1 byte and 2 byte numbers.

Comment: @AlexJohnson: I don't understand your question.  If `my_value` were 150, the output of this code would be `'\x00\x96'`, i.e. two bytes with a first byte of 0.